Why is the intersection point of the diagonals of a regular polygon always the center?
Drawing the long diagonals of an even sided regular polygon, why is the intersection point always equidistant from the vertices?
This is an assumption in many problems, but I have not seen it explicitly proven anywhere. I understand that all polygons have a circle in which it is inscribed, but what is the proof for why the diagonals must intersect at the center of this circle?
I have tried using congruent triangles, but using this method seems lacking in information to prove any congruent triangles without assuming what we want to prove. Proving that each side of the octagon is parallel to its opposite side would prove congruent triangles, but would not prove that each pair of congruent triangles is congruent to each other.

As an FYI: MSE is not a "do my work/homework for me" site. Such posts (e.g. "PSQs") are in poor taste, downvoted, & closed; we expect users to put in effort! If you want meaningful help, [edit] your post to add relevant context (more), e.g. relevant definitions, your work/attempts, the problem's source, where you're stuck, what you do/don't understand & have learned recently, & so on. If needed: this is helpful for formatting LaTeX, & Approach0 can help find past questions.

Is it sufficient to point out that the vertices of a regular polygon always lie on a circle, and the point in question is the center of the circle? If not, please [edit] your question to be more specific about what you seek an answer to!

if they would intersect somewhere else than center, say in P different from C, then if one would apply some well chosen transformation (maybe a rotation or reflection) the regular polygon would map to itself but P would move.

Following up on @peterwhy's comment, you seem to be assuming that the regular polygon has an even number of sides.

@Ted Shifrin I didn’t realize that as I have only been working with even sided polygons recently. I have updated the question.

Assume the center of the circumcircle is the origin. Note that a diagonal through vertex $x$ passes through the origin iff $-x$ is also a vertex iff the polygon has an even number of sides.
